# Batch Script - Get Modified Date and File Name into output file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to add Date Modified and File Name information into the output file my batch script creates.

I have a file (info.txt) that contains multiple strings on separate lines. For each string in info.txt, my batch file loops through each text file in a directory finding said string and outputting that line to a separate file called results.txt. See code below.

```
for /F %%i in (info.txt) do (
echo Searching files containing string: %%i
findstr /C:%%i /I \\directory*.txt >> results.txt )
```

For each line in results.txt I would like to add the File Name and Date Modified of each file that the string was found in. Right now results.txt looks something like this:

//directory/file1.txt:Line of data where "string" was found

But I would like it to look more like this:

Date modified of file1.txt | file1.txt | Line of data where string was found

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: 1. see `for /?` for details about the `~` expansion modifiers -- there is one which returns the file date; 2. see `findstr /?` -- you'll find out that there is an option to provide the search strings by a file directly, and you may search multiple files;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `findstr` is processed in the inner `for` loop - an each string from the output is split on two parts (filename `%%B`, remainder `%%C`). `%%~tB` is a file date and time, `%%~nxB` is a file name and extension.

```
for /f %%A in (info.txt) do (
    echo Searching files containing string: %%A
    for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%B in ('findstr /C:%%A /I directory*.txt') do (
        echo %%~tB ^| %%~nxB ^| %%C >> results.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and taking the time to explain!